# Set uiview background colour using constant variables

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview

I have a Uiview that I want to set the background value for using RGB values which are defined in constants the code I currently have it:

```
_view_emailform.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:*redValue green:*greenValue blue:*blueValue alpha:1];
```

The values are then defined in another file:

.h

```
FOUNDATION_EXPORT CGFloat *const redValue;
FOUNDATION_EXPORT CGFloat *const greenValue;
FOUNDATION_EXPORT CGFloat *const blueValue;
```

.m

```
//RGB values for email page box
CGFloat * const redValue = 30;
CGFloat * const greenValue = 49;
CGFloat * const blueValue = 96;
```

However the above code does not work, when I load the view I get a thread error EXC_BAD_ACCESS

Comment: RGB in UIColor represented as values in range 0 .. 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try like this

In Header file

```
FOUNDATION_EXPORT CGFloat const redValue;
FOUNDATION_EXPORT CGFloat const greenValue;
FOUNDATION_EXPORT CGFloat const blueValue;
```

In .m file

```
CGFloat  const redValue = 30;
CGFloat  const greenValue = 49;
CGFloat  const blueValue = 96;

[UIColor colorWithRed:redValue/255 green:greenValue/255 blue:blueValue/255 alpha:1];
```

Note here i didnt used pointers so that declared the values like `CGFloat const redValue;`

Comment: I get "Invalid operands to binary expression ('CGFloat *' and 'int')

Comment: Change the declaration of constants like `CGFloat const redValue;` `*` is not required